# Using ajax pagination (will_paginate) for multiple groups of the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have gotten ajax pagination working using mislav-will_paginate with the js found here: https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki/Ajax-pagination but I have run into a situation that I am not sure how to handle. I have a number of groups (of the same model) and each group has a number of lists that are paginated. I cannot tell which group to load the lists for in the ajax pagination call. This is the code I am using:

```
function ajaxPagination(){
  var container = $(document.body)
  if (container) {
    container.observe('click', function(e) {
      var el = e.element();
      if (el.match('.pagination a')) {            
        new Ajax.Request(el.href, { method: 'get' })
        e.stop()
      }
    })
  }
}

<% @groups.each do |group| %>
   <% lists = group.lists.paginate(:page => params[:group_page], :per_page => 5) %>
   <% lists.each ....  %>
   <%= will_paginate lists, :params_name => "group_page" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to improve your JS to know which 'group' you're clicking.

```
$("#<%= group %>").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("group")) %>");
```

See: http://railscasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax or read it at: http://asciicasts.com/episodes/174-pagination-with-ajax

```
$('.group').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "/group",
       data: { 'group' : $(this).attr('id') }
       success: function(data){
         alert( "Success" );
       }
     });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question.  How do I figure out what group's pagination was clicked in the controller?

Comment: Based on the element that was clicked (note this is in jQuery) (answer updated)